# Menu Wrapping Around and white-space:nowrap making the menu go past the page Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navbar

I am redoing a Wordpress website, and I am having a problem with the menu. I am using the Compass theme and this is what the top menu looks like.

[image]

Then when I do

```
#MainNav {
    width: 100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

in Custom CSS in Wordpress, the menu goes beyond the page.
[image]

Any suggestions? I want the menu to appear in one line and to dynamically resize. I have done extensive Googling and have tried anything I could find, including flexboxes, but nothing has solved it. I am also very new to Wordpress and don't really understand the file structure, and I'm also pretty new to asking on Stackoverflow!

Comment: do we have live preview?

Comment: we need to see the code, changing the menu to flexbox can work to distribute the white space, but if you need to change the actual font-size,  you must use media queries or js. But without the live previous, it's truly guessing

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest way to get my menu to fit in a theme I didn't design is to write CSS overrides that adjust the padding and font size of the list items in the menu. Usually I do this in a media query so that only certain breakpoints are affected by my change. Here's an example of how you could get the menu items to fit nicely. Make the margin-right on the li 0. You can also adjust the font size on the li > a if you need more wiggle room.

[Adjust the margin-right so it is 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkv71.png)

If you were not using a media query, your custom CSS would look like this:

```
#menu .ddsmoothmenu li {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Your idea of flexbox seems to work okay as well. Although the menu may look a little funky on tablet size screens.

[Flexbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuHzD.png)

One final note, I always use a child theme when customizing a theme I didn't design. This way you can, in an organized way, customize the theme and not lose any of your code when the parent gets updated. You can read about child themes here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes